# Test functionality manually by adding maximum records in SQL table, how should i add those many records?

Tags: manual-testing

I have to test functionality manually where , if a background job  fails then a record is added in a table having columns Exception Id, Job Id, Job Name, Exception, Method Name, Service Name, etc. columns. At present there are around 25 background jobs in the application and i want to test the impact of adding maximum records in the table. How should I do that?  Or i have to manually fail jobs to add maximum record in the table (which is practically not possible, as the we can add unlimited records in the table)Is there any way?

I tried to manually fail the job, so that records can be added in the table, however, adding thousands of records manually is practically impossible.
How should i add maximum records in the table manually/ How should i test this scenario?

Comment: Is this application is API driven?
If yes, then the records can be added by triggering API call multiple times using Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing the following :

1. Create various Windows batch jobs covering the 25 background jobs.
2. Create Windows task scheduler such that it is continuously triggered. You may try scheduling the job execution on the same day or spread across multiple days.

What this will do is you no longer need to run the background jobs manually as the task scheduler will take care of this.